# Beautiful soup id object null

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to manipulate the number on the capacity counter for 'Depot Birmingham' on this site : https://www.theclimbingdepot.co.uk/leeds/news/capacity-counter

Multiple buttons in the dropdown have the attribute id = 'Count'

When I run my code, i get a = None

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.theclimbingdepot.co.uk/leeds/news/capacity-counter'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

a = soup.find("div", {"id": "count"})
print(a)
```

How do i find this capacity count number?

Comment: What is the expected output for this code?

Comment: The webpage is invalid. I can't load it  in Firefox.

Comment: The expected output varies between 0 and about 100 , now it is on 90

Comment: The webpage is valid for me on chrome? not sure why it is invalid for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print all depots, capacities and current counts, you can use this example:

```
import re
import requests
from ast import literal_eval
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.theclimbingdepot.co.uk/leeds/news/capacity-counter'
media_url = 'https://portal.rockgympro.com/portal/public/{pkg}/occupancy?&iframeid=occupancyCounter&fId='

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
pkg = soup.select_one('.media_embed script')['src'].split('=')[-1]
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(media_url.format(pkg=pkg)).content, 'html.parser')

names = {o['value']: o.get_text(strip=True) for o in soup.select('option')}
data = literal_eval(re.search(r'var data = ({.*?});', soup.body.script.string, flags=re.S).group(1))

print('{:<30} {:<10} {}'.format('Name', 'Capacity', 'Count'))
for k, v in data.items():
    print('{:<30} {:<10} {}'.format(names[k], v['capacity'], v['count']))
```

Prints:

```
Name                           Capacity   Count
Depot Manchester               170        166
Depot Nottingham               105        79
Depot Leeds (Pudsey)           82         59
Depot Birmingham               150        103
Big Depot Leeds                105        69
Depot Climbing Sheffield       235        131
```